# Can't get my program to animate multiple patches in python matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, plot, simulation

I am attempting to animate two different particles in matplotlib (python). I just figured out a way to animate one particle in matplotlib, but I am havign difficulties trying to get the program to work with multiple particles. Does anyone know what is wrong and how to fix it?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_dpi(100)
fig.set_size_inches(5, 4.5)

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 100), ylim=(0, 100))
enemy = plt.Circle((10, -10), 0.75, fc='r')
agent = plt.Circle((10, -10), 0.75, fc='b')



def init():
    #enemy.center = (5, 5)
    #agent.center = (5, 5)
    ax.add_patch(agent)
    ax.add_patch(enemy)

    return []

def animationManage(i,agent,enemy):
    patches = []

    enemy.center = (5, 5)
    agent.center = (5, 5)

    enemy_patches = animateCos(i,agent)
    agent_patches = animateLine(i,enemy)

    patches[enemy_patches, agent_patches]

    #patches.append(ax.add_patch(enemy_patches))
    #patches.append(ax.add_patch(agent_patches))

    return enemy_patches

def animateCirc(i, patch):
    # It seems that i represents time step
    x, y = patch.center
    # 1st constant = position and 2nd constant = trajectory
    x = 50 + 30 * np.sin(np.radians(i))
    y = 50 + 30 * np.cos(np.radians(i))
    patch.center = (x, y)
    return patch,

def animateLine(i, patch):
    x, y = patch.center
    x = x + 1
    y = x+ 1
    patch.center = (x, y)
    return patch,


def animateCos(i, patch):
    x, y = patch.center
    x = x + 0.2
    y = 50 + 30 * np.cos(np.radians(i))
    patch.center = (x, y)
    return patch,

def animateSin(i, patch):
    x, y = patch.center
    x = x + 0.2
    y = 50 + 30 * np.sin(np.radians(i))
    patch.center = (x, y)
    return patch,


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animationManage, 
                               init_func=init, 
                               frames=360,
                               fargs=(agent,enemy,),
                               interval=20,
                               blit=True)


plt.show()
```

Working code for animating one particle

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_dpi(100)
fig.set_size_inches(5, 4.5)

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 100), ylim=(0, 100))
enemy = plt.Circle((10, -10), 0.75, fc='r')
agent = plt.Circle((10, -10), 0.75, fc='b')

def init():
    enemy.center = (5, 5)
    agent.center = (5, 5)
    ax.add_patch(enemy)
    ax.add_patch(agent)
    return enemy,

def animateCirc(i, patch):
    # It seems that i represents time step
    x, y = patch.center
    # 1st constant = position and 2nd constant = trajectory
    x = 50 + 30 * np.sin(np.radians(i))
    y = 50 + 30 * np.cos(np.radians(i))
    patch.center = (x, y)
    return patch,

def animateLine(i, patch):
    x, y = patch.center
    x = x + 1
    y = x+ 1
    patch.center = (x, y)
    return patch,


def animateCos(i, patch):
    x, y = patch.center
    x = x + 0.2
    y = 50 + 30 * np.cos(np.radians(i))
    patch.center = (x, y)
    return patch,

def animateSin(i, patch):
    x, y = patch.center
    x = x + 0.2
    y = 50 + 30 * np.sin(np.radians(i))
    patch.center = (x, y)
    return patch,


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animateCos, 
                               init_func=init, 
                               frames=360,
                               fargs=(enemy,),
                               interval=20,
                               blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_dpi(100)
fig.set_size_inches(5, 4.5)

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 100), ylim=(0, 100))
enemy = plt.Circle((10, -10), 0.75, fc='r')
agent = plt.Circle((10, -10), 0.75, fc='b')


def init():
    enemy.center = (5, 5)
    agent.center = (5, 5)
    ax.add_patch(agent)
    ax.add_patch(enemy)

    return []


def animationManage(i,agent,enemy):
    animateCos(i,enemy)
    animateLine(i,agent)
    return []


def animateLine(i, patch):
    x, y = patch.center
    x += 0.25
    y += 0.25
    patch.center = (x, y)
    return patch,


def animateCos(i, patch):
    x, y = patch.center
    x += 0.2
    y = 50 + 30 * np.cos(np.radians(i))
    patch.center = (x, y)
    return patch,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animationManage,
                               init_func=init,
                               frames=360,
                               fargs=(agent,enemy,),
                               interval=20,
                               blit=True,
                               repeat=True)


plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am new to matplotlib so it took me a while to figure out haha

If you don't mind, can you take a look at a more recent question I posted? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446295/cannot-animate-clones-of-the-same-patch-in-python-matplotlib